# how to set the base Href in a angular application?

Tags: angular, deployment, cpanel

Application path on server : public_html/samples/asiatride_design/

I just try $ ng build --prod="true" --base-href="https:xxxx.in/samples/asiatride_design/"
/"

In angular.json outputpath : dist/Asia

by running https:xxxx.in/samples/asiatride_design/ throws these errors

styles.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this..

```
ng build --prod="true" --base-href="https:xxxx.in/samples/asiatride_design/"
```

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   
  <base href="https:xxxxx.in/samples/asiatride_design/">                                     
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.0a6eaf67d09f82c90f46.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.1026f97b75690fa3ccb9.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.602b760972a937a6b860.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.0a9a9d83aa68b87e5984.js"></script></body>
</html>

Comment: GET https://xxxx.in/samples/asiatride_design/runtime.1026f97b75690fa3ccb9.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
xxxxx.in/:23 GET https://xxxxx.in/samples/asiatride_design/styles.0a6eaf67d09f82c90f46.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2xxxxx.in/:26 GET https://xxxxxx.in/samples/asiatride_design/polyfills.602b760972a937a6b860.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
favicon.ico:1 GET https://xxxxx.in/samples/asiatride_design/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Copy all the files from my Angular Project "dist" folder to your PROD Web Server Destination Folder

Comment: It is not work for me..the same error displays on console